# Xamarin display an image from a network shared folder

Tags: c#, xamarin, imagesource

I am trying to display an image stored in a shared windows directory in Xamarin Forms and I can't get it. When I do it through an internet URL it works without problems.

What am i doing wrong?

#### XAML

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding PhotoGalleryModel.ImageSource}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        <ActivityIndicator Color="Blue" IsRunning="{Binding Source= {x:Reference image}, Path=IsLoading}" 
                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.05, 100, 100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
        <Button ImageSource="left.png" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.05, 0.05, 100, 100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Button ImageSource="right.png" Command="{Binding NextCommand}"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95, 0.05, 100, 100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

#### MODEL

```
public List<string> ImagesList { get; set; }

private ImageSource _imageSource;
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            _imageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

#### VIEWMODEL

```
private void LoadImages()
    {
        var windowsAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "user", "password");
        var source = new SmbFile(sharedFolder, windowsAuth);

        var files = source.ListFiles();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.GetPath().ToUpper().EndsWith(".JPG") || file.GetPath().ToUpper().EndsWith(".JPEG") ||
                file.GetPath().ToUpper().EndsWith(".PNG") || file.GetPath().ToUpper().EndsWith(".GIF"))
            {
                var imagePath = file.GetPath().Substring(file.GetPath().IndexOf("/"));
                PhotoGalleryModel.ImagesList.Add(imagePath);
            }
        }

        if (PhotoGalleryModel.ImagesList.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = PhotoGalleryModel.ImagesList[0];
            PhotoGalleryModel.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(filename));
            PhotoGalleryModel.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(filename);


            var file = new MediaFile(filename, () => new MemoryStream());

            PhotoGalleryModel.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();
                return stream;
            });

        }
        else
        {
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Info", "Can't load any image", "Ok");
        }
    }
```

When I debugg, the values of vareables are:

[image: ImagesList][image: Variables in debug]

I triet ImageSource.FromUri, ImageSource.FromFile and ImageSource.FromStream without satisfactory result.

Comment: Check if you have the permission of access the folder .

Comment: Where is the SmbFile type coming from? It is not part of .NET, Xamarin, or Android SDK that I can find. That said, I don't think use of smb protocol is available on Android or iOS. I think your best option is to make a web server and share the files over http/https.

Comment: It is not a permissions problem. The problem is that according to the Output tab, the file is not available instead when I do ctrl+c ctrl+v in in the file explorer, I open the image without problems.

[0:] Could not load image named: {0}: file: //srvdoc/compartit/fotos equips/6A0BW000001/IMG_8834.JPG
[0:] FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: file: //srvdoc/compartit/fotos equips/6A0BW000001/IMG_8834.JPG

Comment: SmbFile is a NuGet package --> More info http://sharpcifsstd.dobes.jp/

Answer (score 0):

### The solution has been to create a Web Server that serves the photos.

In code, load the images throught WebClient class.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string imageUrl = string.Format(WebServer + "/" + Folder + "/" + ImageName);
byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(imageUrl);
image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```